# Argument list too long libcurl c program error

Tags: c, ssl, ftp, libcurl

I am using a C program to connect to an ftp server and upload a file. Previously the server was not using SSL and I was able to do the file upload using the following code :

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl)
{

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, throw_away);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "username");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "password");

    if (CURLE_OK != (res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftpb.****.com")))
    {
        printf("Failed to check ftp url, Error : %s : %d\n", curl_easy_strerror(res), res);
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);

    // Connection establishment timeout
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    printf("Trying to connect...\n");
    if (CURLE_OK != (res = curl_easy_perform(curl)))
    {
        /* If fail to connect */
        printf("FTP connection failed...%s : %d\n", strerror(res), res);
    }
    else
    {
        /* If connected succesfully */
        printf("Connected to FTP successfully...\n");

      /****** proceed with upload ******/
    }
}
```

After the ftp server switched to use SSL certification, I added the following line to my code to use SSL:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
```

Now, when I run the program, my application fails to connect to FTP and show the message :

> "FTP connection failed...Argument list too long : 7"

The same error is obtained even if I do not add the `CURLOPT_USE_SSL` part.

I am able to connect to the ftp server using Filezilla (only if I add ftps to the address). Adding ftps in my code gives the error:

> "FTP connection failed...Device not a stream : 60"

Anybody knows a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the line

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

The application does not try to validate the SSL certificates now and proceeds with the connection

Comment: **never**  disable certificate verification for code you actually run outside of experiments...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `strerror()` on a return code from libcurl. libcurl provides its own `strerror()` version for its return codes. See [curl_easy_strerror](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_strerror.html).

You can also see the errors on the [libcurl-errors](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) man page, and there you learn that 7 means `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT: "Failed to connect() to host or proxy"`. This is probably because you don't run the ftp server on port 21 which is the default port for FTP.

The error 60 you then mention is `CURLE_SSL_CACERT` which indicates you got further but libcurl failed to verify your server.

Comment: I changed strerror to curl_easy_strerror. Now I am getting the error messages as you mentioned. But the port number is 21 itself because I am connecting to the server in filezilla using on port21. This error comes when I am not using ftps in the URL name. When I add ftps I am getting error 60. How to avoid this since my machine verified the certificate when using filezilla

Comment: When you're using FTPS it uses another port by default: 990, and I already explained that your FTPS session fails because libcurl can't verify your server cert. If filezilla did that, then make libcurl use the same ca bundle. I guess that filezilla just skipped it though...